# MVC 3 area using wrong controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using nopCommerce 2.3 and trying to setup a custom Area but the area tries to use the main applications Home controller during run-time and explodes. nopCommerce already has an area called "Admin" that is setup as a separate project and I'm simply trying to follow that architecture. I created a new MVC 3 application and removed all of the login related files and web.config registrations related to profiling and account registration. The area I created is clearly registering with the main application because you can browse its url path. However when you visit its path (http://mysite/backoffice/) it explodes because its trying to use the HomeController.cs file that is in the main application instead of the HomeController.cs that is in my area's assembly (Backoffice.dll). The assemblies/namespaces are completely different between my area project and the main project so I don't know why its confused. Is my registration correct below?

Here is my area registration:

```
namespace Backoffice
{
    public class BackofficeRegistration : AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get { return "Backoffice"; }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Backoffice_default",
                "Backoffice/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, area = AreaName },
                new[] { "Backoffice.Controllers" }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. see here: http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/16098/new-mvc-3-area-registration.aspx#66171